# Django admin- inlines and collapse fields

Tags: django, django-admin, inline

I am using inlines to allow the editing of the Drivers and Riders objects from Family in the admin, as shown below.  I would like the Driver and Rider objects to be collapsed, but it appears that that only works for fields in the class, not fields coming from an inline.  Is there a way to collapse  Rider and Driver as listed below?

Thanks!

```
class LegAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('drive_date', 'start_time', 'endpoint')

class DriverInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Driver
    extra = 0

class RiderInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Rider
    extra = 0

class FamilyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DriverInline, RiderInline]



#admin.site.register(Driver)
#admin.site.register(Member)
#admin.site.register(Rider)
admin.site.register(Leg, LegAdmin)
# admin.site.register(DriveDay)
admin.site.register(Carpool)
admin.site.register(Family, FamilyAdmin)
admin.site.register(DrivingPreference)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could quite easily accomplish this with javascript, just load it within the model:

**example**

```
class Media:
   js = ('/media/admin/custom/js/inlinecollapsed.js',)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still very new to Django and to programming so I'm not quite sure how to use the advice you've provided

Comment: The Media class adds a custom js (or any media file) to the admin by using the extrajs blocks.. Within the js you can create any effect you want